# XML maxHeight and performance

Tags: android, xml, performance

Does maxHeight parameter has impact on perfomance in Android APP? If yes, what I can do to improve this.
Example of my ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Inflated in loop like:

[image]